# Get the ID for a category using only the slug in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a few categories in my wordpress, I need to get the ID for these but all I have is the slug.

is there a way to get this using the slug?

Comment: It is a custom taxonomy?

Comment: This really shows a lack of effort. There is a built in WordPress function `get_category_by_slug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For example you can try this:

```
  $idObj = get_category_by_slug('category-slug'); 
  $id = $idObj->term_id;
```

You can read more about this here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug

**If you use a custom taxonomy you can't use** `get_category_by_slug`.

Then you have to use `get_term_by`.

## Example:

```
$category = get_term_by( 'slug', 'military', 'product_cat' );
```